# AWS Athena - data from last 2 calendar years

Tags: amazon-web-services, date, amazon-athena, date-parsing, datepart

would anyone be able to advise on how to bring in results from the last 2 calendar years? I'd like this to be dynamic, and show data from the current year + the previous year.

I'm currently using `MYDATE > current_date - interval '2' year` , but this is giving me all data from the last 2 years starting today, so is going back into 2021.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I am trying to pull in results from the last 2 calendar years only

Comment: How about just converting to year.  So your filter would be something like `year(MYDATE) >=  year(current_date) -1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `date_trunc`.

For example `MYDATE >= date_trunc('year', current_date - interval '1' year)`.

Running the above filter (on the 2023-11-15 of November), then it gets evaluated with: `MYDATE >= '2022-01-01'` , so you have data from the previous year (complete) and for the partially current year.

Comment: Thanks so much for this - that's worked perfectly and the logic makes total sense, thanks again!